# Doppelter Akkusativ in 'Ich schere mich einen Dreck darum'

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Betrachten wir folgenden Satz:

> "Ich schere mich einen Dreck darum!"

Offenbar sind sowohl "mich" als auch "einen Dreck" Nominalphrasen im Akkusativ. Das erscheint mir sehr ungewöhnlich. Vergleichbare Beispiele fallen mir auch nur mit anderen Ausdrücken von Desinteresse ein, etwa:

> "Es kümmert mich einen feuchten Dreck!"
>
> "Es interessiert mich einen Scheiß!"

Die Beispiele sind keinesfalls gehobene Sprache, insofern kann man sie als Idiome der Umgangssprache abtun. Auf der anderen Seite scheinen "einen Dreck" und die anderen direkten Objekte auch eine andere Bedeutung zu tragen, als der Akkusativ.

Man kann deswegen auch ein interessanteres grammatikalisches Phänomen vermuten. Was kann darüber erzählt werden?

Comment: Die Phrasen im Beispiel sind Adverbialbestimmungen (genauer: Modal -- wie schere ich mich? wie kümmert es mich? wie interessiere ich mich?). Die vermeintlichen Pronomen im Akkusativ sind Teile von reflexiven Verben. Das einzige Objekt in den drei Sätzen ist das „darum“. Die doppelten Akkusative scheinen also eher unabhängige Koinzidenzen zu sein.

Comment: Der Kommentar von @Toscho ist doch eigentlich schon die Antwort. Martin, fehlt Ihnen noch etwas oder würden Sie akzeptieren?

Answer (score 4):

Das bekannteste Beispiel für den doppelten Akkusativ ist das Verb "lehren":

> Ich lehre ihn das Schreiben.

Dies ist weder umgangssprachlich (sondern eher gehoben), noch hat es mit Desinteresse zu tun.

Answer (score 1):

Toscho schreibt in einem Kommentar:

Die Phrasen im Beispiel sind Adverbialbestimmungen (genauer: Modal — wie schere ich mich? wie kümmert es mich? wie interessiere ich mich?). Die vermeintlichen Pronomen im Akkusativ sind Teile von reflexiven Verben. Das einzige Objekt in den drei Sätzen ist das „darum“. Die doppelten Akkusative scheinen also eher unabhängige Koinzidenzen zu sein.

Answer (score 0):

In diesen Sätzen mit doppeltem Akkusativ ist der zweite Akkusativ eine Angabe für wieviel. Man kann sagen:Das kostet (dich) einen Euro/einen Dollar). Ich glaube die obigen Sätze kann man in diese Rubrik tun. Genauer habe ich das noch nicht untersucht.